# Load Balancing DNS with Google Cloud Platform

Tags: domain-name-system, load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, nameserver

I plan to achieve load balancing by using Google to balance NS/DNS between each of three servers.

I am setting up three servers with cluster DNS, records are replicated between each server.

I plan to setup `NS1/2.example` to point towards Google's Load Balancer (Anycast) instead of pointing `NS1/2.example` to each individual server.

How could I achieve that? What should I be aware of?

Comment: Why are you hosting your own DNS at all?

Comment: @ceejayoz Requirement of the customer, they want to host their own DNS, replicated over all their servers.

Comment: I don't know anything about "Google Load Balancer" but in summary putting a load balancer that is not specifically designed for DNS in front of a nameservers is not a good idea at all. Other than that, shouldn't Google be able to help you in your endeavor if you use/intent to use their services? As for "would this approach be beneficial(performance?" (sic) this is far too broad as a question, as you are not giving any details at all in what you attempt to achieve. Important points among others: volume of queries, spread geographically, TTLs, etc.

Answer (score 3):

1. Create an Instance Template
2. Create a Managed Instance Group (MIG)
3. Create a Network Load Balancer pointing to MIG

Note that load balancing UDP has a problem where it doesn't answer the client with the load balancer as the source IP, which causes the client to reject these requests.
To solve this you need to create a rule (using iptables or nftables) to replace it when the packet is outgoing the server.

More info at [How to use UDP with Google Cloud Network Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/udp-with-network-load-balancing)

Answer (score 0):

You want to run your DNS service (load balanced) in the Compute Engine using a few VM's.

There are several choices - if you want something reliable and scalable I'd recommend using either [Managed Instance groups](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups#managed_instance_groups) or Kubernetes.

**In case of MIG's** you configure one VM and then [create an image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-images/create-machine-images) that's being used as a template for the VM's in the group. Group itself is [autoscaled](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler) based on your settings.

> Managed instance groups (MIGs) offer autoscaling capabilities that let you automatically add or delete virtual machine (VM) instances from a MIG based on increases or decreases in load. Autoscaling helps your apps gracefully handle increases in traffic and reduce costs when the need for resources is lower. You define the autoscaling policy and the autoscaler performs automatic scaling based on the measured load and the options you configure.

**Second solution is Kubernetes**. Configure your VM, make a container and run it in [Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/kubernetes-engine-overview).

Kubernetes offers a built in feature to load balance any service you want to run. You just need to expose it as a [loadbalancer type](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps#creating_a_service_of_type_loadbalancer).

Depending on the volume of traffic your service will be getting it will be [scaled down (or up) accordingly](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler).

> GKE's cluster autoscaler automatically resizes the number of nodes in a given node pool, based on the demands of your workloads. You don't need to manually add or remove nodes or over-provision your node pools. Instead, you specify a minimum and maximum size for the node pool, and the rest is automatic.

You can set up the [minimum number](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler#minimum_and_maximum_node_pool_size) of nodes so that it will be always available without the need to spin up new instances.

> You can specify the minimum and maximum size for each node pool in your cluster, and cluster autoscaler makes rescaling decisions within these boundaries. If the current node pool size is lower than the specified minimum or greater than the specified maximum when you enable autoscaling, the autoscaler waits to take effect until a new node is needed in the node pool or until a node can be safely deleted from the node pool.

**You can of course do everything "the hard way"** and have three VM's running your DNS service and a [TCP/UDP load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network) in front of them.

Comment: Hello @CharlotteWells and welcome to StackOverflow! Please remember to [react to answers for your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). 
That way we know if the answers were helpful and other community members could also benefit from them. Try to [accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that is the final solution for your issue, upvote answers that are helpful and comment on those which could be improved or require additional attention. Enjoy your stay!